# How to create HorizontalScrollView with multiple layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm beginner in android developpement and I want create a HorizontalScrollView who contains 2 RelativeLayout. Like this app :

["img 1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UICIn.png)

And after clicking on a button or scrolling, a second layout appears

["img 2"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGGrx.png)

My current code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context="fr.hazpeople.lolbuildcreator.ChampActivity">

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/aatrox_bg"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:paddingRight="-1dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon_champ"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minWidth="72dp"
            android:minHeight="72dp"
            android:src="@drawable/aatrox"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/background"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- HorizontalScrollView here -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is ViewPager.

Here is an android example: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

For changing by clicking a button you may want to use PagerTabStrip